# android , how can I make a view's width be wrap content and max width 50%

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout in which I have to display two text views on the same line , if the the texts in the text views are short they should be wrap content and displayed one beside another , if the text is long the textviews should expand but no longer then 50% of the parent's width . My problem is that I don't know how to set max width to 50% of the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LinearLayout` for that with `horizontal` orientation.

> Sample code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_one_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="key"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_separater"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_two_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am doing like this now but the problem with this is that the two texts will appear far from each other . I want them to be close to each other in case of short texts and expand to a maximum of 50% of the parent for long texts

Comment: Use RelativeLayout for it,with firstText  left alignment of the otherText

Comment: I will try this , I am able to set some approximate max width so that the first will stretch to approximate the middle of the parent , but still I do not know if there is a way to set max width to exactly 50% to have a nice balanced design

Comment: @Marcel look into the updated answer. Please put the one stub view separator so the first will stretch up to the separator & next will start from there. Its exact the 50% of the screen